# Path traversal with multiple conditions filter on all vertices

Tags: arangodb

I would like to perform a path traversal where I apply a multiple condition filter on all vertices.

Basically I would like that every vertices matches either `a == true` or `b == true`.

It is easy to do it for one of the two:

```
FOR v, e, p IN 0..5 OUTBOUND 'objects/key' GRAPH 'stix_graph'
    FILTER p.vertices[*].a ALL == true
    RETURN p
```

or even both condition reunited:

```
FOR v, e, p IN 0..5 OUTBOUND 'objects/key' GRAPH 'graph'
    FILTER p.vertices[*].a ALL == true AND p.vertices[*].b ALL == true
    RETURN p
```

But I don see how I could achieve either `a` or `b` for on every vertex...

Comment: Why do not you just use 
`FOR v, e, p IN 0..1 OUTBOUND 'objects/key' GRAPH 'graph'
    FILTER v.a == true OR v.b == true
    RETURN p`? Or do you need that all the vertices on the way to the final vertex also fit that criteria?

Comment: Yes the idea is that I should stop on the way if one vertex doesn't match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [inline projection](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/AQL/Advanced/ArrayOperators.html#inline-projection) or [inline filter](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/AQL/Advanced/ArrayOperators.html#inline-filter) in order to achieve the result you want.

Here is a sample AQL using inline projection:

```
FOR v, e, p IN 0..5 OUTBOUND 'objects/key' GRAPH 'graph'
    FILTER p.vertices[* RETURN CURRENT.a OR CURRENT.b] ALL == true
    RETURN p
```

Here is a sample AQL using inline filter:

```
FOR v, e, p IN 0..5 OUTBOUND 'objects/key' GRAPH 'graph'
    FILTER COUNT(p.vertices[* FILTER CURRENT.a OR CURRENT.b]) == COUNT(p.vertices) 
    RETURN p
```

**Important Note:** This approach will only perform well if you traverse a relatively small graph. If you have really huge and deep graph the performance may suffer as both inline projection and inline filter are considered by ArangoDB query optimizer as a `CalculationNode`. I.e. ArangoDB will not stop the traversal on a first vertex where the condition returns `false`. It will have to continue the traversal because the filter condition has a calculated value and  it can not know in advance if the result of that calculation is `true` of `false` for the next vertices. So, it will do a bit of extra traversals/calculations under the hood, but it will still return the result you expect.

If you want to apply this filter for a really huge graph I believe the correct approach would be to add a bit of redundancy to your data and put that `a == true` or `b == true` value into a separate attribute which you can efficiently use in your filter condition.

Comment: Thank you, I tried on my graph and it is not performing well, but it answers the questions :-) 
As for the redundancy it is not that easy. I used 2 boolean values for the sake of the question but in fact one of the condition is to check if a value is present in a list. i.e. `'value' IN CURRENT.b`.

Comment: Yeah, the performance might be a problem here. In our project we use very big AQL queries with many traversals and filters. When you have a complex business logic is not always simple to find a solution with a good performance.